# Returning a value from a function to a global variable

Tags: python, variables, debugging, global

Greetings fellow Coders!
Quick disclaimer i'm new to the world of coding and currently learning Python, happy for all the infos and help i get!

So i'm trying to code the mastermind game if your are not familiar with it here is a wikipedia arcticle:  [Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game))

Im trying to work with global variables, but everytime the global variable is used in a function it dosent return it into the global variable the variable just sets back to its original value.

If u need more info from me please let me know!
looking forward to hearing from you.

```
import random
colors = "YORPGB"
global secret  
global round
global hits
global close 

def gen_random_secret():
    secret = ""
    for i in range(4):
        n = random.randrange(6)
        secret += colors[n]
    return secret

def get_guess(force_valid_input):
    while True:
        guess = input(f"Available letters: {colors}\nPut in a 4-letter Word with the available letters, there can be duplicates! ").upper()
        
        if len(guess) ==4:
            return guess
        else:
            if not force_valid_input:
                return None
            print("Wrong Input try again!")

def check_guess(guess,secret):
    hits = 0
    close = 0
    for i in range(4):
        if guess[i] == secret[i]:
            hits += 1
    
    for color in colors:
        close += min(secret.count(color),guess.count(color))
    close = close - hits
    
    return hits, close

def start_game():
    print("Welcome to the Mastermind game!\nGenerating random code...")
    round = 1
    history = []
    hits = 0
    close = 0
    secret = gen_random_secret()
    while round<=12:
        guess = get_guess(True)
        check_guess(guess,secret)
        
        print(f"Hits: {hits} Close: {close}\n")
        if hits == 4:
            break
        round += 1
        history.append((guess,hits,close))
    print()
    for row in history:
        for color in row[0]:
            print(f" {color}", end="")
        print(f" | {row[1]} {row[2]}")
    print()
    if hits == 4:
        print(f"Congratz u guessed it the code was: {secret}")
    else:
        print(f"You ran out off attempts, you lose bitch!\n the secret Word was {secret}")

start_game()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: There appears to be little reason to use global variables at all here. Use arguments and return values, or define a class that use instance attributes to communicate between methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `global` within the function to let the function know to use the global variable.

For example:

```
def gen_random_secret():
    global secret
    secret = ""
    for i in range(4):
        n = random.randrange(6)
        secret += colors[n]
    return secret
```

Instead of:

```
global secret
def gen_random_secret():
    secret = ""
    for i in range(4):
        n = random.randrange(6)
        secret += colors[n]
    return secret
```